# in unity, i am trying to get swipe to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in unity i am trying to get swipe to work. this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class swipe : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector3 fp;   //First touch position
    private Vector3 lp;   //Last touch position
    private float dragDistance;  //minimum distance for a swipe to be registered
    private List <Vector3> touchPositions = new List<Vector3>; //store all the touch positions in list

    void Start(){
        dragDistance = Screen.height*20/100; //dragDistance is 20% height of the screen 
    }

    void Update(){
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)  //use loop to detect more than one swipe
        { //can be ommitted if you are using lists 
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) //check for the first touch
            {
                fp = touch.position;
                lp = touch.position;
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) //add the touches to list as the swipe is being made
            {
                touchPositions.Add(touch.position);
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) //check if the finger is removed from the screen
            {
                //lp = touch.position;  //last touch position. Ommitted if you use list
                fp =  touchPositions[0]; //get first touch position from the list of touches
                lp =  touchPositions[touchPositions.Count-1]; //last touch position 

                //Check if drag distance is greater than 20% of the screen height
                if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance)
                {//It's a drag
                    //check if the drag is vertical or horizontal 
                    if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
                    {   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
                        if ((lp.x>fp.x))  //If the movement was to the right)
                        {   //Right swipe
                            Debug.Log("Right Swipe");
                        }
                        else
                        {   //Left swipe
                            Debug.Log("Left Swipe"); 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
                        if (lp.y>fp.y)  //If the movement was up
                        {   //Up swipe
                            Debug.Log("Up Swipe"); 
                        }
                        else
                        {   //Down swipe
                            Debug.Log("Down Swipe");
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            else
            {   //It's a tap as the drag distance is less than 20% of the screen height

            }
        }
    }
}
```

however, it gives an error: Assets/swipe.cs(9,66): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type
does anyone know the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line of code:

```
private List touchPositions = new List; //store all the touch positions in list
```

`List` is a generic type, and based upon your snippet, you need a list of type `Vector3`. The declaration should be:

```
private List<Vector3> touchPositions = new List<Vector3>(); //store all the touch positions in list
```

note: after updating your code snippet, the erroneous line shows `<Vector3>` correctly, and the error is the missing () before the semicolon.